# vue-cli-service serve reloading in docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx

I'm using @vue/cli-service 4.1.0 to serve my vue application. When running it with vue-cli-service serve command on my host (Mac Os, Darwin 18.5.0), everything works perfectly. But recently I decided to dockerize it (node:13 is a base image, Docker version 19.03.5, docker-compose version 1.25.2). I am using docker and docker-compose and create a volume with my source code inside docker container, running `yarn install && yarn serve` after as initial cmd. But after changing any file outside of docker container, vue-cli-service doesn't rebuild my app. Also I can't reproduce this issue neither on Linux machine nor another Mac Os host.

Since I couldn't find anything close to my problem, I decided to ask for it here.

I am using the following nginx configuration to proxy all requests.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name default;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://front:8080;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you put your code in a named volume, Docker will treat it as user data that must not be modified, and it will ignore changes in the underlying image.  That's not a good match for your application code.  Delete the volume specification, and rebuild the image when the code changes.

Comment: I am not using named volume but mount it to the host system.

Comment: I also have the same problem. The only thing I can think is that vue-cli-service is not noticing the file changes because they are originating on another system. Super weird

Comment: Actually, for a bit more evidence, it seems that even if you run the vue-cli-service serve from within the container and change the file also within the container, it still does not pick up changes. Perhaps an issue with the way that vue-cli-service works on linux vs windows?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you are having a problem with the Hot Reload feature not working in docker? If that is the case, the problem may the port mapping.

It looks like you're mapping the the host port 8080 to the container port 80. I may be wrong here as it's a bit hard to tell.

Try mapping port 8080 on your host to port 8080 on the container

Reference [Hot reload not working with webpack-dev-server and docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861358/hot-reload-not-working-with-webpack-dev-server-and-docker)